# Bootstrap Button_Click Event Not Firing

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form designed with a button which should call a stored procedure.  For now, I just want the button to display text in a textbox (just to make sure the button is working).  However, I cannot get it to fire the button_click event.

Here is what I have:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <section class="container">
        <div class="container-page">                
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3 class="dark-grey">Registration</h3>

                <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="" name="" class="form-control" id="" value="">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="" class="form-control" id="" value="">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <label>Repeat Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="" class="form-control" id="" value="">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="" name="" class="form-control" id="" value="">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                    <label>Repeat Email Address</label>
                    <input type="" name="" class="form-control" id="" value="">
                </div>          


            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3 class="dark-grey">Terms and Conditions</h3>
                <p>
                    By clicking on "Register" you agree to the Terms and Conditions.
                </p>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="btnSumbit_Click">Register</button>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My c# code is:

```
protected void btnSumbit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "Registered";
}
```

Any idea why this will not work?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you are getting a normal `<button>` mixed up with an `<asp:Button>`.

Your current implementation wants to run a javascript function name btnSubmit_Click and does not have any connection to your C# code-behind.

```
...
<asp:Button type="submit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnSumbit_Click" runat="server">Register</asp:Button>
...
```

I haven't been able to test if it works myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use an html button, instead of an ASP Button control (for instance, if you need something other than text in the button), you can still do it like this (using runat=server and OnServerClick):

```
<button runat="server" type="button" id="updateButton" onserverclick="UpdateEmail_Click" class="btn btn-success btn-block" title="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, UpdateCaps %>"><asp:Localize ID="Localize5" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, UpdateCaps %>"></asp:Localize></button>
```

Comment: Works great! Without this, we could not use any of the nice Bootstrap buttons in Asp.Net, and the regular asp buttons are ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a standard HTML button, you need to:

1. Add `runat="server"` to your button.
2. Set your button to use `onserverclick` instead of `onclick`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick(v=vs.110).aspx

So:

`<button runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" onserverclick="Method_Name"...`

Alternatively, you can use Bootstrap classes with the `<asp:Button...` tags as well. You'll simply apply them to an attribute called `CssClass` instead of `class'.

So:

`<asp:Button type="submit" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Method_Name"...`